# Insert Form Checkboxes PHP separated by comma - Retrieve them

Tags: php, arrays, forms, checkbox, csv

I was looking in stackoverflow, but i do not find exactly what I need. I need to insert checkboxes data sent with php into mysql like this 22111,22332,12123,121132.

I have this code (found here in the site)

```
<?php 
foreach($_POST['idecod'] as $check) {
            $sel = $check.',';}

$contenedor = "UPDATE inmdes SET idecod='$sel'";

$insertdb = mysql_query($contenedor) or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

Of course I have the checkboxes as an array:

```
<input name="idecod[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $rs[0]; ?>"  />
```

How can i insert multiple checkboxes like 2211223,2211223,1212233,12332122 or if is just one 222111222..???

And how can i retrive them as an array because i need to use something like this

```
<? php if (in_array('2211223', $idecod)) echo "checked"; ?>
```

To automatically check the previous checked boxes.!

Thanks in advance

Roberto

UPDATE

I have a list of options. These options act/des with checkboxes. I need to:

1.- Be able to register options checked (SOLVED thanks to @prodigitalso)
2.- Be able to automatically check the checkboxes previously checked.

So, I have the codes like this 221122,221133,225566,445522 in the table (mysql). I need the script to check what codes where previously checked (those that are in the table) and check them. For example:

I see the 5 options 221122,221133,225566,445522 and 663322. I check only 4 (221122,221133,225566,445522) and this is UPDATED in mysql database.

I come again to the options page. But previously i checked 221122,221133,225566,445522. So the script check EACH checkbox. So automatically check options 221122,221133,225566,445522 BUT it doesnt check 663322.

RS[0] is the code, for example 221122.

Comment: You are **wide open** to SQL injection.  Learn to do this properly by utilizing prepared queries with PDO, or you **will be hacked** if you haven't been already.

Comment: THanks for the advide @Brad. I use mysql_real_escape_string to avoid SQL injections. I havent in this piece of code, but I use it.! xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `explode` and `implode`.

```
if(isset($_POST['idecod']) && !empty($_POST['idecod'])) {
   $sel = implode(',', $_POST['idecod']);
   $contenedor = sprintf("UPDATE inmdes SET idecod='%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($sel));
   $insertdb = mysql_query($contenedor) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

then when you pull them out just use:

```
$idecodArr = explode(',', $row['idecod']);
```

Comment: Thanks.! It worked very well.!! Now comes the part of pulling data. I tried with this code `$arr = "SELECT idecod FROM inmdes";
$leerdbarr = mysql_query($arr) or die(mysql_error());
$arrdt = array(mysql_fetch_row($leerdbarr));` And this in the checkbox `<input name="idecod[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $rs[0]; ?>" <?php if (in_array($rs[0], $arrdt)) echo "checked"; ?>` The rs is the code, for example 2211220 pulled from another table. So, i have 4 checkboxes, but only 3 were checked, and those 3 are in db like 221122,223322,114455. How can I pull them and use the in_array (or another)

Comment: cont... So i can check automatically the checkboxes that were previosly checked.?? Thanks.!

Comment: your code isnt making sense to me. what is `$rs[0]`? can you update your original question to show the query for `$rs`. and the structure o the tow tables.

Comment: I Solved It.!! xD This is the code to pull the array from database

`$arr = mysql_query("SELECT idecod FROM inmdes");
$leerdbarr = mysql_fetch_array($arr) or die(mysql_error());
$idecodArr = explode(',', $leerdbarr[0]);`

And this is the conditional in the checkbox

`<input name="idecod[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $rs[0]; ?>" <?php if (in_array($rs[0], $idecodArr)) echo "checked"; ?>`

RS[0] is a variable, in this case, the code (Ex: 223344)

Thanks @prodigitalson

Answer (score 1):

You can use `implode` and `explode` function to do this

```
$string = implode(",", $array);

$array = explode(",", $string);
```